# Can't view the pdf in the browser after enabling SSL, instead.. it is downloaded (Asp.net MVC 5)

Tags: file, pdf, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

Before Enabling SSL, i can view pdf in the browser.

This link has no **https** ( [http://localhost:50895/Home/BookDetail/1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sIo2U.png) )

After Enabling SSL, i can't view PDF and it is downloaded instead of showing it.This link has **https** ( [https://localhost:44382/Home/BookDetail/1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l2T0j.png) )

I have tried iframe , object , embed in view
with Both Functions in Controller below.

==========Controller =================================================

```
 [HttpGet]

public ActionResult GetBookSampleByPath(string FullPath)

{

    return File(FullPath, "application/pdf");

}


  [HttpGet]

public FileStreamResult GetPDF(string FullPath)

{

     FileStream fs = new FileStream(FullPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

     return File(fs, "application/pdf");

}
```

==========View =================================================

```
 <iframe src="@Url.Action("GetBookSampleByPath","Ajax",new { FullPath=Model.FilePath+Model.FileName })"  type="application/pdf"  style="width:100%; height:100%;" frameborder="0"></iframe>


<object data="@(Url.Action("GetPDF","Ajax",new { FullPath=Model.FilePath+Model.FileName }))" type="application/pdf"   style="width:100%; height:100%;">
alt : <a href="~/Upload/BookSample/@(Model.FileName).pdf">test.pdf</a>
</object>


<embed src="@Url.Action("GetBookSampleByPath","Ajax",new { FullPath=Model.FilePath+Model.FileName  })"  type="application/pdf"  style="width:100%; height:100%;"  />
```

=================================================

All Three View work if i switch back to 
[http://localhost:50895/Home/BookDetail/1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sIo2U.png).
And Also Both function in controller is working too.

But it is not working if i open from 
[https://localhost:44382/Home/BookDetail/1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l2T0j.png).
Pdf is not showing and downloaded instead.

Does **Http://** and **Https://** has something to do with it? 
I am confused.
Please Help me !

[This is screenshot for http://localhost:50895/Home/BookDetail/1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sIo2U.png)

[This is screenshot for https://localhost:44382/Home/BookDetail/1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l2T0j.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well...
I just happen to find out this solutions...Not an actual solutions..

========================================================

Here is how i do this

```
var Host = "your hosting address eg:  www.google.com";  

var Path = "your path eg: /upload/pdf/";

var filename = "a.pdf";


<embed src='https://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?embedded=true&url=@(Host+Path +filename)'  width="500" height="375" style="width:100%; height:100%;">
```

=================================================================

This is not a good solutions..
i am still searching for another solution...
but i hope it help